# How to pass the hook state values

Tags: reactjs

I want to console.log(City) but in child file
and I use react tool in the browser surely see the Hook State:'xxx'

parent first file(fxx.js)

```
export const UserForm =() => {
 const[city,setCity]=useState('')

function nextStep(){
 setStep(step+1)
}
function prevStep(){
  setStep(step-1)
 }


 switch(step){
  case 1:
   return (
  <>

    <UserDetail
    nextStep={nextStep}
    submitValue={submitValue}
    City ={e => setCity(e.target.value)}
     />
      </>
   )
   case 2:
   return (
     <>
   <PersonDetail 
   nextStep={nextStep}
   prevStep={prevStep}
   />
   </>
   )
 }
}
```

child second file(sxx.js)

```
function UserDetail(props) {

 console.log(City)

function conti(e){
  e.preventDefault()
  props.nextStep()
}

 return (
  <>
        <TextField onChange={props.City} defaultValue={props.City}/>
        <Button variant="outlined" color="primary" onClick={conti}></Button>
  </>
 )
}
```

**console.log(City)not work**
I try :
this.state.City
state.City
City
Hook.City

they ain't work
I'm confused how state value passing
the main idea is to get the "City" value in other js files
is that the only way to save the value in the props??

pls help

Comment: Ciao, can you put more code to undestand where the problem is? How the father is connected to the chid? Where props is assigned... Just few more lines. Thanks :)

Comment: Balius, go and checkout , how data flows in React.js . In this case props.city will give you data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ciao, your problem is on how you pass `City` prop on `UserDetail` in this line:

```
City ={e => setCity(e.target.value)}
```

You passd a function, not a value to log. Anyway I understand why you passed like this. Because you want also to set city on `TextField`.

My suggestion is to use 2 prop: one to read city and one to set city. So your code becomes:

parent first file(fxx.js)

```
export const UserForm =() => {
 const[city,setCity]=useState('')

function nextStep(){
 setStep(step+1)
}
function prevStep(){
  setStep(step-1)
 }


 switch(step){
  case 1:
   return (
  <>

    <UserDetail
    nextStep={nextStep}
    submitValue={submitValue}
    setCity={e => setCity(e.target.value)}
    City={city}
     />
      </>
   )
   case 2:
   return (
     <>
   <PersonDetail 
   nextStep={nextStep}
   prevStep={prevStep}
   />
   </>
   )
 }
}
```

child second file(sxx.js)

```
function UserDetail(props) {

 console.log(props.City)

function conti(e){
  e.preventDefault()
  props.nextStep()
}

 return (
  <>
        <TextField onChange={props.setCity} defaultValue={props.City}/>
        <Button variant="outlined" color="primary" onClick={conti}></Button>
  </>
 )
}
```

So now `console.log(props.City)` logs City prop and `TextField`s `onChange` function sets the value of `city` in parent component.